# Owl Carousel 2 - Spinner Loader behind images

Tags: owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have a strange behaviour with spinner loader which is showing behind the images but lazy loading is declared as `false` in options.

```
$('.galleryowl').owlCarousel({
    margin: 10,
    autoWidth: true,
    dots: false,
    dotsEach: false,
    lazyLoad: false,
    loop: false
});
```

[image]

Do you have any clue which can be the problem?

Regards

```
<div class="galleryowl owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="owl-stage"
            style="transform: translate3d(-615px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 2255px;">
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966999.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17967002.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966992.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966994.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966997.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966995.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17967011.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966998.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966990.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966984.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: auto; margin-right: 10px;"><img class="img-responsive"
                    src="https://66822b0c4798708fd342-4c20877d1724d8eec18944c33f4c4dbd.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/17727/1386208/medium/17966991.jpg"
                    style="opacity: 1;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-nav disabled"><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev"><span
                aria-label="Previous">‹</span></button><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next"><span
                aria-label="Next">›</span></button></div>
    <div class="owl-dots disabled"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup it on fiddle for us to look at it, as of now its difficult to say why.

one quick solution could be to hide loader with css.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in my custom css owl file.
I removed a background spinner image that was loaded by error.